# Solving these jqueries working together

Tags: jquery, html

I've got two scripts that work great separately but don't work exactly as I want together.

I have 4 buttons and 4 target div's (the first div is initially displayed and the other 3 are hidden),The first thing I want to do is on clicking one of the 4 buttons it displays a target div and hides the other 3 div's using this script:

```
// Toggle Divs
var currLayerId = "text0click";
function togLayer(id){
     if(currLayerId) setDisplay(currLayerId, "none");
     if(id)setDisplay(id, "block");
     currLayerId = id;
}

function setDisplay(id,value){
     var elm = document.getElementById(id);
     elm.style.display = value;
}
```

and then the second is to slide the screen down to the target div that's just opened using this code:

```
// Slide down function for four buttons
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var slidePosition = jQuery('#mens_section_link').offset().top;

    jQuery('#mens_scroll').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:slidePosition}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var slidePosition = jQuery('#womens_section_link').offset().top;

    jQuery('#womens_scroll').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:slidePosition}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var slidePosition = jQuery('#kids_section_link').offset().top;

    jQuery('#kids_scroll').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:slidePosition}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var slidePosition = jQuery('#equipment_section_link').offset().top;

    jQuery('#equipment_scroll').click(function(){
        jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop:slidePosition}, 'slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Both scripts separately do just what they are intended too fine. However when I combine them the first script opens the div's fine (great) and scrolls to the first div (this is because the div is initially displayed), however all the other div's (which are initially set too hidden) does the opposite and always scrolls to the top of the page.

JSFiddle of the code with both scripts: http://jsfiddle.net/vpbuz106/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't make such crazy mix of jQuery and pure javascript, do it either with one of 'em, i mean or
`var elm = document.getElementById(id);` or `var elm = $('#elmId')`, and you've attached 2 handlers to the same event in two different ways, so works just the one you've attached through `onclick` attrubute. All you need is just one function

```
$('.layer-toggle').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $that = $(this);

    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $that.offset().top
    }, 'slow')

    if ($('.togglable-div:visible').length){
       $('.togglable-div:visible').hide();
       $('#' + $that.attr('id') + '_div').show();
    }
});
```

and remove the `onclick` attribute from your markup and change the ids like from your `text0click` and so one to smth more meaningful like `your-btn-id+div` to achieve smth like `mens_scroll_div`. The rest you see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpbuz106/1/)